# How can I remove spaces and "\n" from a string?

Tags: c#, string

I have strings that look like this:

```
"\n        間違う\n      "
```

It's really a `\n` and some spaces.

How can I remove these from the string?

Comment: Do you care about whitespace just at the start and end, or do you care about whitespace in the interior as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) which will remove any white-space (including new-lines, tabs, etc) from both left and right ends of a string:

```
var s = "\n        間違う\n      ";
var trimmed = s.Trim();

// output
// 間違う
```

If you want to remove line-breaks between text (like `間\n違う\n`) then you can use [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var s = "間\n違う\n";
var trimmed = s.Trim().Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
// output
// 間違う
```

Comment: But I  also need to remove the "\n" characters

Comment: `\n` is considered whitespace @Alan2

Comment: you must be escaping the `\\` then.  Where is the string coming from?  See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SavW5p) for an example

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Trim.

```
var s1 = "\n 間違う\n      ";
var s2 = s1.Trim();
Debug.WriteLine(s2);
```